John Chrysostom On the Priesthood 3.9
What is the Greek word Chrysostom uses for authority?
“The blessed Paul did not suffer them even to speak with authority in the church.”

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this question
